# How to deploy JFrame interface from link on a web page?

Tags: java, swing, deployment, jframe, java-web-start

I have a Java code making a `JFrame` interface. I want to deploy same interface (same looking) on a web page. For example taking a scenario: I click on a link on web page then same interface (as frame) opens and it performs functions same way as frame works in Netbeans.

Is there any way to accomplish it? Can I deploy same interface on a server?

Comment: *"..functions same way as frame works in Netbeans."*  Not if if the code does things like loading a `new ImageIcon(String)`.

Answer (score 3):

[Java Web Start](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/) will let you access your existing Swing app from a web page without any code changes. However, the app won't be ON the web page, but rather a download and auto-launch kind of thing.  If you've already done Swing development, then you may already be familiar with this since all of the Java tutorials have this.

EDIT:

For an example of how this works, see the [How to Use Password Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/passwordfield.html) tutorial, and click the Launch button on the web page.

Comment: You are saying to create a .rar file and deploy it? But i want to take input from user on the interface ON Web page and update a database with those input. How can i do that without change in code?

Comment: @Rachit: where does anyone state anything about a .rar file?

Comment: See also the [JWS info. page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

Comment: In response to EDIT: I donot want application to be first downloaded and used from a desktop. I want it to run on web page for example as soon as user hits launch it should direct him to web page with password interface and he enters the password on web browser itself. all the work should happen ON web page. How do I do that?

Comment: @Rachit: Per your initial request `I click on a link on web page then same interface...` This is exactly what happens with JWS. The download only happens if the user never downloaded before, or if a newer version of the app is available. Otherwise, it's seemless to the user: they click a link on a page and your JFrame is shown. That being said, if you really have your heart set on a web page, then you could either try the suggestions from Vivan P. or roll up your sleeves and write a web app. Either way, you now have extra code to write, possibly a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can either deploy your application as an applet, or look at using [GWT](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/).